# How can I use declarative authorization without always keeping the user id as a param in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

Declarative authorization seems to require params[:id] to do its validation and I want to use paths like /profile and /dashboard where the user is stored in the session and not the URL. But it breaks. Any ideas on how I can do this without hacking the gem itself?

Answer (score 3):

> Declarative authorization seems to
>   require params[:id] to do its
>   validation

This is only true if you are relying on `filter_resource_access` to set instance variables in the controller. You can set up your own authorization scheme by specifying `filter_access_to`. This allows you to set up your own custom methods which can be based on whatever you like -- session variables, model attributes, etc.

The controller section in this [introduction](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) explains `filter_access_to` and gives some examples.

Comment: Specifically, use a before_filter to assign your User object to `@user`.  Then `@user` will be used in the authorization check.

Answer (score 1):

If you have users in your application, why don't use a authentication plugin? I  use Restful authentication and with a few work I have complete session management. For your problem this plugin has a helper method `current_user` that retrieves the user with opened session.

I think its better rely on plugins like Restful Authentication (or AuthLogic like the  response #1) than implement your solution, but you'll know better your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use AuthLogic, but as far as I know "current_user" is not going to be accessible through a route.

You would need to check, in the controller, if params[:id] == "current_user" (as a string) and then do some logic based on that... i.e:

```
if params[:id] == "current_user"
  @user_id = current_user.id
else
  @user_id = params[:id]
end
@user = User.find(@user_id)
```

A very simplistic example, but it should illustrate the type of logic you're going to need to get the current_user from a custom route. You could also just map a named route for current_user to it's own controller action, but that's not very RESTful and would [most likely] duplicate functionality you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Use [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) so you can get a `current_user` method.

Use `filter_access_to` instead of `filter_resource_access`.

Comment: I had used filter_access_to :all but again same is the problem. Any other solutions.